# Implementing a Flutter Questionnaire with Yes/No Options and Result Calculation

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently working on a Flutter app project that involves creating a user questionnaire. This questionnaire will consist of seven questions, and users will be presented with Yes or No options to respond. The primary objective is to evaluate if users exhibit signs of anxiety based on their responses. Here are the specific requirements:

a) The questionnaire should comprise seven questions, with one question displayed per page. This series of questions should eventually lead the user to a final result page.

b) If the user answers "Yes" to four or more of these questions, we should display a message indicating, "You are exhibiting signs of anxiety. It is crucial to seek professional help immediately." Additionally, we need to showcase boxes containing pictures of various techniques that users may apply to alleviate anxiety.

c) Conversely, if the user answers "Yes" to three or fewer questions and the majority of their responses are "No," we should display a message saying, "You do not exhibit signs of anxiety." In this case, there is no need to display the technique boxes.

I've currently have made some progress by looking through some guides online, already inserting certain codes to work on this, however it's still not complete and I need more proper coding to fully accomplish this overall objective:

anxiety*home*component.dart:

```
import 'package:anxiety_app/src/ui/question_page.dart';
import 'package:coolicons/coolicons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ionicons/ionicons.dart';


import '/src/riverpod/bottom_tab_provider.dart';

class AnxietyHomeComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnxietyHomeComponent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                "My Spaces",
                style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1.5,
                    )),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 12,
                  vertical: 4,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "SOS",
                  style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Coolicons.settings_future),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 48,
                width: 48,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      ""
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Internal Help",
                      style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "anxiety management & control",
                      style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Text("Self Care"),
              const Spacer(),
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Text("See All"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 2,
                    width: 42,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 54,
                        width: 54,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            )),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 12,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Talk",
                        style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: 6,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16,
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Feature",
            style: GoogleFonts.balsamiqSans(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 1.5,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 84,
                  width: 84,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                        "",
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 16,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Let's help identify your anxiety",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => QuestionPage()
                          ));
                        },
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 1.5,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 12,
                            vertical: 6,
                          ),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text("Get Started", style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 17,
                            ),),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, ref, _) {
              final index = ref.watch(amBottomTabProvider);
              return Container(
                height: 64,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    index == 0
                        ? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 0;
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 1.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12,
                          vertical: 4,
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(Ionicons.home),
                      ),
                    )
                        : IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 0,
                      icon: const Icon(Ionicons.home),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    index == 1
                        ? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 0;
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5,),),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4,),
                        child: const Icon(Ionicons.apps_outline),
                      ),
                    )
                        : IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 1,
                      icon: const Icon(Ionicons.apps_outline),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    index == 3
                        ? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 0;
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5,),),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4,),
                        child: const Icon(Ionicons.document_text_outline),
                      ),
                    )
                        : IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => ref.read(amBottomTabProvider.notifier).state = 3,
                      icon: const Icon(Ionicons.document_text_outline),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Question_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../data/question.dart';

class QuestionPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<QuestionPage> createState() => _QuestionPageState();
}

class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionPage> {



  List<Question> questionList = getQuestions();
  int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  int score = 0;
  Answer? selectedAnswer;


   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 15, 32),
       body: Container(
         margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 32),
         child:
         Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
           const Text(
               "Questions to exhibit signs of anxiety",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24,
              ),
           ),
           _questionWidget(),
            _answerList(),
            _nextButton(),
         ],),
       ),
     );
   }

   _questionWidget() {
     return Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
         Text(
           "Question ${currentQuestionIndex+1}/${questionList.length.toString()}",
           style: const TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
           fontSize: 20,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
         ),
         ),
         const SizedBox(height: 20),
         Container(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
           width: double.infinity,
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.orangeAccent,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
           ),
           child: Text(
             questionList[currentQuestionIndex].questionText,
           style: const TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 18,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
           ),),
         )
       ],
     );
   }

   _answerList(){
     return Column(
        children: questionList[currentQuestionIndex].answersList.map(
              (e) => _answerButton(e),
          )
           .cast<Widget>()
           .toList(),
     );
   }

   Widget _answerButton(Answer answer){

         bool isSelected = answer==selectedAnswer;

         return Container(
           width: double.infinity,
           margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
           height: 48,
           child: ElevatedButton(
             child: Text(answer.answerText),
             style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
               shape: const StadiumBorder(),
               primary: isSelected? Colors.orangeAccent: Colors.white,
               onPrimary: isSelected? Colors.white : Colors.black,
             ),
             onPressed: (){

               if(selectedAnswer == null){
                 if(answer.isCorrect){
                   score++;
                 }
                 setState(() {
                   selectedAnswer = answer;
                 });
                }
               },
           ),
         );
   }

   _nextButton(){

     bool isLastQuestion = false;
     if(currentQuestionIndex==questionList.length-1){
       isLastQuestion=true;
     }

     return Container(
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,

       height: 48,
       child: ElevatedButton(
         child: Text(isLastQuestion? "Submit" : "Next"),
         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
           shape: const StadiumBorder(),
           primary:  Colors.yellowAccent,
           onPrimary:  Colors.black ,
         ),
         onPressed: (){
            if(isLastQuestion){


             showDialog(context: context, builder: (_)= _showScoreDialog() );
            }else {

             setState(() {
               selectedAnswer = null;
               currentQuestionIndex++;
             });
             }
            },
       ),
     );
   }

   _showScoreDialog(){
     bool isPassed = false;

     if(score >= questionList.length * 0.6){

       isPassed = true;
     }
     String title = isPassed?"You are exhibiting signs of anxiety. It is crucial to seek professional help immediately" : "You do not exhibit signs of anxiety";

     return AlertDialog(
       title: Text(title +" | Score is $score",
         style: TextStyle(color:isPassed ? Colors.green:Colors.redAccent),
       ),
       content: ElevatedButton(child: const Text("Restart"),
         onPressed: (){
         Navigator.pop(context);
         setState(() {
           currentQuestionIndex =0;
           score=0;
           selectedAnswer = null;
         });
       },),
     );
   }
}
```

Question.dart:

```
class Question{

  final String questionText;
  final List<Answer> answersList;

  Question(this.questionText, this.answersList);

}

class Answer{
  final String answerText;
  final bool isCorrect;

  Answer(this.answerText, this.isCorrect);
}

List<Question> getQuestions(){
  List<Question> list = [];

  list.add(
    Question("Feeling nervous, anxious, or on edge",
        [
         Answer("Yes", true),
         Answer ("No", false),
        ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Not being able to stop or control worrying",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Worrying too much about different things",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Trouble relaxing",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Being so restless that it is hard to sit still",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Becoming easily annoyed or irritable",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  list.add(
    Question("Feeling afraid, as if something awful might happen",
      [
        Answer("Yes", true),
        Answer ("No", false),
      ],
    ),);

  return list;
}
```

I expect to get the full and proper code to accomplish said objective above.

Comment: Please tell us a specific problem and not a "here's a task I have to do, solve it for me".